# How to set form as invalid manually in jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
$("#form").valid()
```

How to set form as invalid manually?

```
$("#frm_Index").valid() = false;
```

Comment: Is `valid()` a jQuery library you're using, or are you confusing it with the native [`checkValidity()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement#methods) method?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Please first ***>>>[Search for related topics on SO](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+invalidate+form+site%3Astackoverflow.com)<<<*** and  if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [`[<>]`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: Add a non-visible, required input and make it empty?